# How to retrieve dynamically added/deleted rows of data using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the data from dynamic rows in html table using jQuery. I mentioned the below code snippet for creating dynamic rows

jQuery function

```
 $("#madd").click(function(){

         if ($("#selected_text").html()!=''){
          $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#fmly_dtls").find('input').val('');
    }else{
        alert('Please save the data');
    }
 });
```

Table id is `#fmly_dtls`, so I added row into table when I clicked on add button. After adding 5 rows I am trying to retrieve that data from dynamic rows data.

```
$("#finalbtn").click(function(){
    var membrdt='';
$("#fmly_dtls tr").each(function (i) {         
    var myValue2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first'); 
    alert($(this).children('td:first').val());
});
```

`#finalbtn` is html button. When I clicked the button. Is there any issue on above to retrieve the data?

jsfiddle :-
[JSFIDLE URL](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshr4u/WnuuM/1/)

Comment: please fix formatting, and consider posting an example to jsfiddle and adding a link to it.

Comment: As per your comments i added jsfiddle.please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Edit:**
Since you are trying to get the value of a `textbox` and not the `td` itself, you should use `val()` to get the value. Also, looking at your fiddle, the type of text box is `text` and not `textbox`. Here is the updated [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WnuuM/3/).

```
$("#finalbtn").click(function() {
    var membrdt = '';
    $("#fmly_dtls tr").each(function(i) {
        var myValue2 = $(this).find('td:first :text').val();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks.If iam using .text()/.val() function.it will shown the blank data.So how to retrived the value of row.

Comment: @user1357722 maybe it's too late to reply, but if you haven't found a solution, check out the updated answer.